# For what reason would a function with void return type be constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++20

To give a specific example, the push_back() member functions of std::vector became constexpr in C++20.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: You have come to cppreference.com already, why not step a little farther? [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the requirements of a `constexpr` function is that it can only call other `constexpr` functions.

So, this allows `push_back`() to be called from some other `constexpr` function that might, actually, return something useful.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and provide an example of a constexpr function that calls the push_back() member function on an instantiation of std::vector?

Comment: The body of the function could look like this: `vector<int> v{}; v.push_back(20); return v[0];`. C++20 allows `vector` to work in constexpr code due to constexpr allocation rules.